# AnimatedSplashScreen PageTransitionType error

Tags: flutter, dart, android-animation, splash-screen, null-check

I have a problem using `AnimatedSplashScreen`, everything works fine to the moment I add a `pageTransitionType`. Then I get an error:

> The following _CastError was thrown building AnimatedBuilder(animation: Listenable.merge([kAlwaysCompleteAnimation➩ProxyAnimation, kAlwaysDismissedAnimation➩ProxyAnimation]), dirty, state: _AnimatedState#bd6f7):
> Null check operator used on a null value

This is a simple app which generates that problem:

```dart
import 'package:animated_splash_screen/animated_splash_screen.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:page_transition/page_transition.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: AnimatedSplashScreen(
        splash: Icon(Icons.person),
        pageTransitionType: PageTransitionType.scale, //with that line commented there is no error
        nextScreen: HomePage()
      ),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

I have tried running many commands like *flutter pub get* etc.

Also, dependencies in `pubspec.yaml` are running smoothly:

```dart
animated_splash_screen: ^1.1.0
page_transition: ^2.0.1-nullsafety.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually after all these years, I have found the answer myself.

The problem was, that the `Animated Splash Screen` Widget actually has two different parameters. One for the transition of the Splash animation `splashTransition`, and one for the next screen transition `pageTransistionType`.

So The simple app, that solved the question asked and allows for using a scale transition would look like this:

```dart
import 'package:animated_splash_screen/animated_splash_screen.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:page_transition/page_transition.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: AnimatedSplashScreen(
          splash: const Icon(Icons.person),
          splashTransition: SplashTransition.scaleTransition,
          pageTransitionType: PageTransitionType.fade, //with that line commented there is no error
          nextScreen: HomePage()
      ),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and could recreate it.
As I understood, you are trying to use the Property 'scale' for the pageTransitionType, like:

```
pageTransitionType: PageTransitionType.scale,
```

If you want to use scale, you will have to use (for example) a Navigator.push() within a PageTransition like this:

```
ElevatedButton(
    child: Text('Scale Transition Second Page'),
        onPressed: () {
        Navigator.push(
            context,
            PageTransition(
            curve: Curves.linear,
            type: PageTransitionType.scale,
            alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
            child: SecondPage(),
            ),
        );
    },
),
```

For using .scale as TransitionType you'll need an 'alignment' like it's shown in my example.

Further information:
https://github.com/kalismeras61/flutter_page_transition/issues/53#issuecomment-983511302 
https://pub.dev/packages/page_transition/example

Comment: thank you for your answer. Unfortunately this still doesn;t explain how to use pageTransitionType with AnimatedSplashScreen. My main problem is that AnimatedSplashScreen only fades in, and then goes straight to the main page instead of fading out smoothly

Answer (score -1):

Not sure how to solve the scale problem specifically, but you can change the transition type to another kind, for instance,

```
pageTransitionType: PageTransitionType.fade
```

Comment: yeah i did that to finish my project, but still i would like to make a scaled transition :/

Answer (score -1):

```
import 'package:page_transition/page_transition.dart';
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.

Answer (score -1):

Apparently, we must add the page_transition as a dependency.

There's a youtube video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q-e5t3qnB_M&t=1s

Here's the GitHub with the documentation
https://github.com/kalismeras61/flutter_page_transition

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Unfortunately, as I stated in my question I have the page_transition already in my dependencies. Also because I am using an animated_splash_screen I cannot follow directly the tutorial and can't come up with a solution myself